# how to make a tkinter GUI that calculates how much money you would make in a given time with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am facing a problem with making a Tkinter GUI that calculates how much money you would make in a given time. It is simply a stopwatch with a start and stop button.  When you start the stopwatch, you will get next to the stopwatch how much money you would have made in the given time on the stopwatch. What I cannot seem to do is that money calculation part. Everything works fine until the money calculator turns to €00,998 and has to add 1 euro to to the euro variable, and change cents to 0. i want it to add 1 euro, and change cents to 0, when the cents are equal to 998 cents, and start adding cents again until it's equal to 998 etc. But what my code is doing now, is when the cents are equal to 998 cents, it starts adding more euro's than 1, and the whole label starts to shake.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as font
import time

euro = 0
cent = 0
hcent = 0
salaris = (7.2/3600)
class Timer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.text_variabel = tk.StringVar()
        self.root.geometry('455x300')
        self.root.resizable(False,False)
        self.root.configure(bg='lightgreen')
        self.start_tijd = None
        self.is_running = False

        self.make_widgets()
        self.root.bind('<Return>', self.startstop)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def make_widgets(self):
        tk.Label(self.root, textvariable=self.text_variabel, font='ariel 30', fg='white', bg='lightgreen').pack()
        #tk.Label(self.root, textvariable=self.text_variabel, font='ariel 15', fg='green', bg='black').pack()
        btn_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        btn_frame.pack()
        tk.Button(btn_frame, text='Start', command=self.start, font=font.Font(size=25, family='Helvetica'), width=6).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        tk.Button(btn_frame, text='Stop', command=self.stop, font=font.Font(size=25, family='Helvetica'), width=6).pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

    def start(self):
        if not self.is_running:
            self.start_tijd = time.time()
            self.timer()
            #self.money()
            self.is_running = True

    def timer(self):
        self.text_variabel.set(self.format_time(time.time() - self.start_tijd))
        self.after_loop = self.root.after(50, self.timer)

    def stop(self):
        if self.is_running:
            self.root.after_cancel(self.after_loop)
            self.is_running = False

    def startstop(self, event=None):
        if self.is_running:
            self.stop()
        else:
            self.start()

    @staticmethod
    def format_time(elap):
        global cent, hcent, euro, salaris
        hours = int(elap / 3600)
        minutes = int(elap / 60 - hours * 60.0)
        seconds = int(elap - hours * 3600.0 - minutes * 60.0)
        hseconds = int((elap - hours * 3600.0 - minutes * 60.0 - seconds) * 10)
        #euro = int(0)
        #secondes_grens = 10 or 20 or 30 or 50 or 59
        #cent = int(0)

        #hcent = (seconds * salaris)*1000
        ksalaris = salaris * 1000
        while True:
            if cent <=996:
                cent = (seconds * ksalaris) + (minutes * ksalaris)*60 + (hours * ksalaris)*3600
                #elif hours > 0 and seconds == 0:
                #elif hours ==1:
                 #   cent = (hours * salaris)*100000
                #elif hours > 0 and seconds > 0:
                 #   cent = (seconds * salaris)*1000 + (hours * salaris)*100000
            else:
                euro = euro + 1
                cent = 0
            return '%02d:%02d:%02d:%1d' % (hours, minutes, seconds, hseconds), '€%02d,%03d' % (euro, cent)


Timer()
```

Comment: Please edit. There is no question here. What is your question? Please be (programming) specific, because as it is stated, it is a too generic question, and will be voted to be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either split the result into its component parts (`import math` required):

```
    cents = (seconds * ksalaris) + (minutes * ksalaris)*60 + (hours * ksalaris)*3600
    cent, euro = math.modf(cents)
    cent = int(cent*1000)
    return '%02d:%02d:%02d:%1d' % (hours, minutes, seconds, hseconds), '€%02d,%03d' % (euro, cent)
```

or
use float formatting (you may have to declare the locale to get a , (comma) as the seperator.

```
cents = (seconds * ksalaris) + (minutes * ksalaris)*60 + (hours * ksalaris)*3600
return '%02d:%02d:%02d:%1d' % (hours, minutes, seconds, hseconds), '€%05.3f' % (cents)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are forgetting that there are a lot of minutes between the first minute and the first hour.

Do you need to have all of those `if` clauses? Or can you just have a straightforward seconds, minutes, hours accumulator?

```
ksalaris = salaris * 1000
while True:
  if cent <= 996:
    cent = (seconds * ksalaris) + (minutes * ksalaris)*60 + (hours * ksalaris)*3600
  else:
    euro = euro + 1
    cent = 0
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer. The code you gave worked perfectly fine until the money calculator turned €00,998 and had to add 1 euro to the euro variabel, and change cent in 0. what i am trying to do, is to keep the money calculator adding cents, till the centsare equal to 998, than i want the calculator to add 1 euro, change cents to 0, and start adding cents again until it's equal 998 cents etc.  Do you maybe know what i am doing wrong?